# AWS Glue Sagemaker Notebook "No module named awsglue.transforms"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-sagemaker

I've created a Sagemaker notebook to dev AWS Glue jobs, but when running through the provided example ("Joining, Filtering, and Loading Relational Data with AWS Glue") I get the following error:

[image]

Does anyone know what I've setup wrong/haven't setup to cause the import to not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to download the library files from [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-glue-jes-prod-us-east-1-assets/etl/python/PyGlue.zip) for Glue 0.9 or [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-glue-jes-prod-us-east-1-assets/etl-1.0/python/PyGlue.zip) for Glue 1.0 (Check your Glue jobs for the version).

Put the zip in S3 and reference it in the "Python library path" on your Dev Endpoint.

Comment: Where is this documented?

Comment: This solution does not work for me. Please see below what did work for me in the end

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and the selected solution did not work for me.

I did manage to get working by using cloud formation (AWS::Glue::DevEndpoint).
Through trial and error I noticed that you can't specify both **NumberOfNodes** and **NumberOfWorkers** at the same time. You have to specify one or the other.

Using **NumberOfNodes: 5** resulted in the exact same error as specified in the question. But using the 2nd option worked perfectly.

So to conclude, to fix this error you can use CloudFormation and make sure to use the **NumberOfWorkers** property.

Answer (score 1):

Add `AWSGlueServiceNotebookRole` to your Dev Endpoint IAM Role, restart your kernel and rerun

Answer (score 0):

hm... this approach doesn't work for me.
I've just put zip to "Python library path", referenced to it and it doesn't work